# estoy intentando montar una imagen con css y html

Tags: html, imagen, ccs

```css
.hore {
    background-image: url(../jpg.jpg/hero.jpg);
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
    <div class="contenido-hero">
        <h2 class="titulo">cuidados y curiosidades de la robotica </h2>      
      
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-rocket" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        <path d="M4 13a8 8 0 0 1 7 7a6 6 0 0 0 3 -5a9 9 0 0 0 6 -8a3 3 0 0 0 -3 -3a9 9 0 0 0 -8 6a6 6 0 0 0 -5 3" />
        <path d="M7 14a6 6 0 0 0 -3 6a6 6 0 0 0 6 -3" />
        <circle cx="15" cy="9" r="1" />
        </svg>
        
    
       <p>san antonio de prado</p>
    
      <a href="#">contactar</a>
   </div>
</section>
```

intento insertar una imagen con html y css y cuando cargo la pagina la imagen no la carga y verifique el codigo y esta bien estructurado y no le falta nada

Comment: Tu directorio, en su nombre tiene ese símbolo de punto? `jpg.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el selector dice "hore" no "hero" como creo que pretendias hacer. Verifica el directorio de la imagen tambien.

Comment: gracias bro telo agradezco